# namespace prefix "myapp" is not defined in Xamarin While Building App?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I want to build a Toolbar in Xamarin app. When i want to create a menu it shows me error saying that "namespace prefix "myapp" is not defined". Here is code.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android-auto">
<item android:id="@+id/action_reply"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_reply"
    android:title="Reply"
    myapp:showAsAction="always" />
<item android:id="@+id/action_undo"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_undo"
    android:title="Undo"
    myapp:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Can anyone help me with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you use `myapp` prefix? Use `android` instead.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android-auto">
<item android:id="@+id/action_reply"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_reply"
    android:title="Reply"
    android:showAsAction ="always" />
<item android:id="@+id/action_undo"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_undo"
    android:title="Undo"
    android:showAsAction ="never" />
</menu>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It solved my problem. I have one problem. My Toolbar TextColor is Black. My Friend ask me to do this. But it is showing following error. Can you suggest some improvement. "app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" and Error is "no resource identifier found for attribute "popupTheme" in package "android-auto"

Comment: @Zeeshan it would be much easier to help you if you create new thread (as that's a different question) and provide more details.

Comment: reach limit of questions. i have to wait 2 days for next questin. can  i mail you?

Comment: So your goal is to use "@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" for popups?

Comment: i want to change my toolbar text color from black to white. but the above code is showing error on build.

Comment: @Zeeshan I recon you should create new question as I can find nice solution (though it should be simple) but maybe someone else could help.